# Android Question (for game)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a game, at the end i show a "Game Over" if the player does not follow some instructions.... the problem is android seems to stay on that state, when i go back to the menu and come back in.. i still dont have a way to play again, the game is coded in the main activity and has Runnables and OnTouch events, also I have a splash screen that when click it goes to the other activity where the game starts.... I am new to Android, what is the best way to terminate the Thread and then send them to the first Activity or splash screen?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very difficult to help without seeing any code. However, an Activity can self-terminate by calling finish(), if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you Phil, some people get overwhelmed when the whole code is posted so I wanted to ask first. I added the finish(); and it terminates it but as soon as it does it it brings me back to the second activity and I can do anything.. in reality I want to finish it and send it to the first Activity

Comment: Got it, it seems like the previous Activity before it goes to the new one still remembers the values of the previous game.. so i had to reset eveything before the finish(), and then when they click on the splash screen it starts as a new game. Thank you for the help

Comment: If the Activity1 needs to update when Activity2 terminates, startActivityForResult / onActivityResult may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use static variables they will be 'remembered' unless explicitly set in the View constructor or onSizeChanged etc. For example  x = x + 5, can increase x every time you start the same game if x is static, because it 'remembers' x from the previous play - one needs to be aware of this.